# using Scrapy getting error

Tags: python

```
import scrapy

class MyCouponSpyder(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "toscrap-coupon"
    start_urls = ["https://www.groupon.com/coupons/stores/macys.com?c=058fc9a8-01a8-4ff4-b714-dc6dcbc5624f"]

    def parse(self,response):
        for reviews in response.xpath("//div[@class='modal show-modal']"):
            yield {
                 'week_menu':reviews.xpath(".//h2[@class='title']/text()").extract_first(),
                 }
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: 2017-09-05 11:20:07 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:

Comment: 2017-09-05 11:20:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.groupon.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)

Comment: tq for ur reply

Comment: 200 status is not an error. Scrapy successfully crawled the page